# How do I use setCellRenderer properly?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jprogressbar, tablecellrenderer

Right now I have this code

```
jTable1.getColumn("Progress").setCellRenderer(new TableCellRenderer() {

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable arg0, Object arg1,
    boolean arg2, boolean arg3, int arg4, int arg5) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new JProgressBar();
    }
});
```

and I want to update it's progress as it keeps going, but of course this code doesn't work.

So I change it to this.

```
jTable1.getColumn("Progress").setCellRenderer(new TableCellRenderer() {

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable arg0, Object arg1,
    boolean arg2, boolean arg3, int arg4, int arg5) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        JProgressBar bar2 = bar; //where bar is another JProgressBar being updated outside.
        return bar2;
    }
});
```

This code works, but the problem is, when there is multiple rows, their columns all update to the same value, which is not what I want.

I want to be able to update the indiviual row's JProgressBar, but how do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

I've done something similar(JSpinner instead of JProgressBar) and I've done it like this:

```
public class SpinnerRenderer implements TableCellRenderer {
    private JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner();

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
            boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {

        checkNotNull(model, "The SpinnerModel from the table model is null");

        if (!(value instanceof SpinnerModel)) {
            System.err.println("Error: The value" + " in cell: row=" + row
                    + " col=" + column + " must be instance"
                    + " of SpinnerModel");
        }else{
            SpinnerModel model = (SpinnerModel)value;
            spinner.setModel(model);
        }

        return spinner;
    }

}
```

You should note that I fetch the data from the table model, where I have separate SpinnerModel for each spinner.

Comment: +1, it's the trick ! @user2519193 For information you should use a [`BoundedRangeModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/BoundedRangeModel.html) instead of `SpinnerModel` with `JProgressBar`

Comment: But where do I put this class in? Just use this class in setCellRenderer?

Comment: You use it like that: table.setCellRenderer(new MyCellRenderer());